# How to dynamically populate the screen width labels?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to dynamically display labels based on the amount of words in a string array, and am trying to make it that whenever a label is going off the screen, even just a portion of it, its x position is reset to the left side and its y position is incremented by a given number. I have the y position done, but I can't reset the x position. Its sort of like the flipboard app when you are choosing topics, a list of topics are displayed. 
[Heres a link to a picture of the code on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDm6m.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can the labels. The real answer is to use a `UICollectionViewController`. Do yourself a favor and do this the the Right Way, even though it's a lot of work to get started: it's the powerful, long-term expandable, idiomatic way.

Tutorial: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

**EDIT**

One nuance is cell sizing. In particular you were not accounting for padding. In general this is not trivial. Here's one simple technique for your particular needs:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize { 
      let sizingLabel = UILabel()
      sizingLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 30)
      sizingLabel.text = topics[indexPath.row]
      sizingLabel.sizeToFit()
      return sizingLabel.bounds.size
}
```

BTW you misspelled "Neue" nas "Neuse" in your code screenshot.
In general post your code as properly formatted code text in your edited question, not in an image. I can't test what I wrote for you because of that, so I'm less certain than I'd like to be.

Comment: I did that and then the output made the words cut off, or not display fully, although in the size function i did set the width dynamically. I did that and now [picture of code](https://i.imgur.com/bRSGZ2w.png) [picture of output](https://i.imgur.com/SETZJPu.png)  `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize { return topics[indexPath.row].sizeWithAttributes(nil) }`

Comment: Edited to include this issue.

Comment: the text doesn't appear over the label, it remains blank with the green background, yet the text is being shown printed in the console. Also thanks for the sizing, as the sizes now work.